# Install ceiling light with wireless switch

Tags: electrical, iot

I’m looking to install a ceiling fixture where none exists. I believe power is already routed through the joists where I’d like to install. Can I have a contractor open the ceiling and put in a wireless relay for power that can be controlled via wireless switch on the wall? Or do I need new wiring that is controllable via directly wired switch?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?  Also, are there switched receptacles in the room already?

Comment: San Francisco. There is a switched receptacle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way house wiring is done in practice one cannot simply wrap an insulation piercing tap around a wire and get power. This is done all the time in cars, but not in houses. If a wire in the attic happened to be passing over the center of a room where you wanted a ceiling fixture, code and practice do not allow a simple tap.

Nevertheless, it is easy to get power to a ceiling fixture by cutting a wire and making proper connections. To tap into a circuit this way one usually is required to make *two* cuts and add some cable in between in order to get enough slack to make all the proper connections.

Hard wired wall switches are still the standard for controlling ceiling fixtures, but no doubt remote switching is possible. Check the electrical inspection where you are to see if what you are contemplating is allowed by the local code.

**EDIT**

If there is a switched receptacle in the room, then the standard thing to do would be to add a cable from the switched receptacle to a new ceiling box. The cable can always go from the switched receptacle or may from the switch box IF there is a neutral there.

Sometimes the switched receptacle is one of a duplex receptacle and the other receptacle is always powered. If so, then both receptacles can be made always powered. You might not need a switched receptacle, if there is an overhead light which is switched

Comment: +1 Note that only special splices are allowed to be concealed in walls or ceilings (and not in all jurisdictions), not junction boxes. Wall mounted wireless switches are becoming common and should meet most electrical code that require a light switch near the room entry door.

Comment: “Wireless light switch” was really helpful. Searched for that and I can see the solution. Thanks!

Comment: So what do you think is the solution?

Comment: Ask for a wireless light relay installed within the always on power that is going in the ceiling. Shouldn't require doing all the work to route new power lines to the wall switch.